# Por que o @ desaparece ao clicar no link

Tags: php, email

Crio um link para redefinição de senha:

```
$mail_message   .= "<a href=$url_sender/redefinir-senha?email=$email_sender&identifier=$identifier_sender&code=$confirmation_code>
    Clique aqui para redefinir sua senha.
</a>";
```

Mas ao clicar no link recebido no email, o arroba( @ ) desaparece.
Observei que esse erro acontece apenas no Gmail.

Comment: Use a função [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) em todas as variáveis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parâmetros de URL devem ser codificados para que os caracteres especiais não interfiram na forma como se interpreta a URL.

No caso do PHP, seria necessário usar uma função como o [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) em cada parâmetro passado.

Por exemplo:

```php
$mail_message .= '<a href="'.$url_sender.'/redefinir-senha?'.
    'email=' . urlencode($email_sender) . 
    '&identifier=' . urlencode($identifier_sender) . 
    '&code=' . urlencode($confirmation_code) . 
    '">Clique aqui para redefinir sua senha.</a>';
```

**Atualização**: também ajustei as aspas para que o atributo `href` tivesse o valor entre aspas duplas. Isso também pode evitar problemas de interpretação do valor da parte do navegador.

Comment: Parece que precisa de uma revisão das aspas. E também: a variável não vai ser reconhecida dentro de aspas simples.

Comment: @brasofilo Não há variáveis entre de aspas simples. Veja que extraí tudo para fora e estou usando concatenação. E acabei de olhar novamente e não encontrei nenhum "desequilíbrio" de aspas.

Comment: tomei a liberdade de corrigir, antes estava com os problemas citados pelo @brasofilo

Comment: @Jader Ok, obrigado.

Answer (score 4):

Outra alternativa é usar a função [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) como no ex. abaixo:

```
$mail_message   .= '<a href="' . $url_sender . '/redefinir-senha?' .
http_build_query(array(
   'email' => $email_sender,
   'identifier' => $identifier_sender,
   'code' => $confirmation_code)) . '">Clique aqui para redefinir sua senha.</a>';
```

Obs.: Não esqueça de enclausurar o `href`, seja com aspas simples ou dupla.

Comment: Ótima sugestão!